# Trouble using AUFS driver in docker with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install and configure docker and having issues switching from the default overlay2 storage driver to the aufs driver. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a AWS EC2 instance. I install docker using [this digital ocean guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04), and when I type `sudo docker info` I can see that it is using the overlay2 driver.

I edit the `/etc/default/docker` file so that `DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 -s aufs"` I then reboot the computer but when I look at the docker info line, it still is overlay2.

I read that installing extra packages is needed in ubuntu so I did run this command but it didn't help:

`sudo apt-get install curl \
    linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) \
    linux-image-extra-virtual`

Is there anything else I can try? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I figured it out using the [official docker installation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/), the trick is to install all of the aufs packages before installing docker.